# Request user for (some kind of) process verification before merging

Tags: github, git-merge, pull-request

I have a Git repo, managed in GitHub. I want to be able to allow merge to `master`, only after a user would manually verify that they took some action.

I have an application that has some unit testing mechanism. For whatever reasons, I can't run those tests on CircleCI (or similar) which is automated solution. I require my developers to run this unit testing manually on their local machines. In order for them not to forget to do so, I want them to verify it (preferably on GitHub) before they can merge.

I imagined it as some kind of a checkbox that needs to be marked in order to be able to merge.

Comment: You should probably dig into those *"whatever reasons"* instead - making humans run a process and tick a box is a colossal waste of time, get robots to do it.

Comment: i know your'e 100% right. but unfortunately it requieres tremendous amount of work due to security issues, Plus currently we won't have enough resources to do so.